# Rails session start event handler

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to do some stuff when ever a new session starts for a user. Which is that is the right place to do it in rails?
I am looking for something similar to session_start for asp.net in global.asax.

In ASP.net there is handler

```
session_start()
{

  // This will be executed everything when a new users visits the site very first time.

}
```

Comment: You might find a file named sessions_controller.rb under app/controllers/users

Comment: @CaffeineCoder there's no such thing in a default Rails project or installed Devise. No reason to assume he has it too.

Comment: Yes I am looking for something framework providers so that it will be useful for any anonymous users too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't there is a corresponding method like ASP, you would need to do conditional setting of session values depending on whether they exist, perhaps in an application controller method (so run on all pages). E.g:

/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
def set_session
  session[:var1] ||= "x" 
  session[:var2] ||= "y" 
end
```

Then at the top of the file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_session
```

Comment: Wouldn't `session[:var1] ||= "x"` do?

Comment: So basically just use the session hash to decided if the request is a first request from the user?

Comment: Thanks D-side, you are right - updated. NMK - I think it's the right way to go but might be proved wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your needs might best be met by setting the session variable in application_controller.rb with a before_filter:

```
before_filter :set_session_thing

def set_session_thing
  session[:your_variable] ||= "your_value"
end
```

That will run before every request. Is that what you're looking for?

You should check out the docs here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#accessing-the-session